# Is using different thread pools for different types of tasks worth the overhead?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I'm designing a class that provides statistical information about groups of Collatz sequences. One of my goals is to be able to process a large number of sequences containing enormous terms (on the scale of hundreds or even thousands of digits) simultaneously, with maximum efficiency.

To this end, I plan on using the best data collection technique for each individual statistic, which means some tasks may be more efficiently dealt with by a `ForkJoinPool`, others by the standard cached and fixed thread pools provided in `Executors`. Would the overhead of creating multiple thread pools, or shutting one down and creating another, if I went that route, cost me more than I would save?

Comment: This is something you would probably need to test empirically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would the overhead of creating multiple thread pools, or shutting one down and creating another, if I went that route, cost me more than I would save?

How could we possibly tell you that?

There is definitely an overhead in shutting down and restarting a thread pool.  If any kind.  Creating threads is not cheap.

However, we have no way of quantifying how much you save by using different kinds of thread pool.  If we can't quantify that it is impossible to advise you on whether your strategy will work ... or not.

(But I think that repeatedly shutting down and recreating thread pools would be a bad idea.  The performance impact of an *idle* pool is minimal.)

---

This "smells" of premature optimization.  (It is like trying to tune the engine of a racing car before you have manufactured the engine block!)

My advice would be to (largely<sup>1</sup>) forget about performance to start with.  For now, focus on getting something that works.  Here's what I would do:

1. Implement the code using the easiest strategy, write test cases, test / debug until it works.
2. Choose a sample problem or set of problems that is typical of the kind you will be trying to solve
3. Implement a test harness that allows you to measure the code's performance for the sample problems.  (Beware of the standard problems with Java benchmarking ...)
4. Benchmark your code.

   - Is it fast enough?  Stop NOW.
   - If not, continue.
5. Implement one of the alternative strategies, and test / debug.
6. Benchmark the modified code.

   - Is it fast enough?  Stop NOW.
   - Is it clear that it doesn't help?.  Abandon it, and try another strategy.
   - Can you tweak it?  If so, try that.
7. Go to 5.

Also, it may be worthwhile implementing the different strategies in such a way that you can tune them or switch between them using command line or config file settings.

---

As a general rule, it is hard to determine *a priori* how well any complicated algorithm or strategy is going to perform.  Generally speaking, there are too many factors to take into account for a theoretical ... or intuitive ... approach to give a reliable prediction.  Benchmarking and tuning is the way to go.

---

<sup>1 - Obviously, if you *know* that some technique or algorithm will perform badly, and you have a better alternative that is about the same effort to implement ... do the sensible thing.</sup>

Comment: I'm relatively new to concurrency and I wanted to make sure that my plan wasn't one of the big "no-no's" among concurrent programmers. But you're right. I tend towards perfectionism and overanalyzing things, so premature optimization is something I'm having to force myself to avoid.

Comment: It is not a big no-no.  I would say that it is *plausible*.  The problems with premature optimization are that 1) you often optimize when it is not necessary (waste of time), 2) you often optimize the wrong thing (waste of time), or 3) your optimizations may turn out to be anti-optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only talking about two different types of pools (fork-join and `Executor` based pools), and you claim that at least some of your tasks are more suited to one type or pool or the other, it is entirely likely that the overhead of using two types of pools is worth it.

After all, you can just keep both types of pools alive and so there is only a *one time* cost to setting up the pools and creating the threads, while the (apparent) benefit of the two pool types will apply across the entirety of your processing. Since you are doing an "enormous" amount of work even small benefits will eventually add up and overwhelm the one-time costs (which are probably measured in micro-architecture per thread).

Key to this observation is that there is no real ongoing overhead for existing but inactive threads in the pool you aren't using.

Of course, that said, the short answer it "just try both approaches and measure it!".